# What are the crabs at World's End?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

When Jack Sparrow is stranded inside Davy Jones' Locker, in At World's End, he is there alone (if we exclude any of his clones) with the Black Pearl on a desert.

He finds a mysterious moving rock, and throws it away. The rock turns out to be some sort of disguised crab and runs off. It fetches hundreds of other crabs, and they all come together to help bring the Pearl back to shore.

**What are these crabs?** I believe they must have some sort of symbolic meaning (e.g., they are the souls of other lost sailors that gave up going back to sea inside the locker), but I don't really have anything to go on aside from pure speculation.

### What are the crabs helping Jack, why did they do it, and what do they represent?

Comment: They're just crabs. They're under the control of Calypso: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33317/31029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33258/why-did-davy-jones-little-white-crabs-help-jack-escape-from-davy-jones-locker/33317#33317) answer in the comments:

> It wasn't Davy Jones', but Tia Dalma's which, afterwards, is revealed to be Calypso.
>
> This is set clear a couple of times during the movie. The first time, while still in the locker and they find Jack, the remaining crabs get under her skirt. Later in the film, when Calypso is released (the scene where she is tied to the ship's mast and starts growing) she scatters into these crabs.